# Is there a graph or ontology that maps diseases to its possible causes or causing diseases?

Tags: pathology

I am looking for a mapping, list, ontology or graph that shows the connection between a diseases and its (currently known) causes and/or risk factors.

For example a well known risk factor for *acute kidney injury* is *diabetes*. There are other diseases whoms risk factor is *diabetes*. This meanse *diabetes* is a *risk factor* for many *diseases*. Maybe if one traverses trough this dependencies and builds a graph out of it, there will interesting clusters and lineages.

I dont know if this is *inherent knowledge* or formulated somewhere in a formal and explicit way (e.g. as ontology).

There is http://disease-ontology.org/, but it does not contain any causes, risk factors, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! I think it would help if the question is further specified. As of now it is rather broad and at least to me unclear what you are exactly after.

Comment: So you are basically looking for an enormous data base that connects diseases with their risk factors and known causes?

Comment: @fileunderwater: Yes, could be a database. I think a ontology would model this behaviour very well. In this sense every node would be a disease or a risk factor (because not every risk factor is a disease), between the nodes you have different links of type "has_cause" and "has_risk_factor". Very much in the way http://disease-ontology.org/ is modelled (click on some concept and then "Visualize"). So this is what i had in mind, but if there exists a database or just a massive text-file, it would also help me!